# How do I convert a column containing state names into corresponding regions in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I made a separate worksheet with each region as a column and the states included into that region as rows. I then named each of these ranges using the define name feature : South, Northeast, Midwest, West.

[image: region data]

I also named the range of states in State column "States"
then I tried to use an ifs function: =IFS(States=South, "South", States=Midwest,"Midwest", States= Northeast,"Northeast", States= West, "West")

[image: Ifs statement]

I've tried a bunch of variations of of these things, i.e. not using the define name function but just using a single cell or an undefined range that I set. I cant figure it out though. Nothing seems to work. In theory I feel like it should work. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

use this formula

```
=IFS(ISNUMBER(MATCH(E3,South,0)),"South",ISNUMBER(MATCH(E3,Northeast,0)),"Northeast",ISNUMBER(MATCH(E3,Midwest,0)),"Midwest",ISNUMBER(MATCH(E3,West,0)),"West")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
=LET(a,TOCOL(A2:C7,1),
     b,TOCOL(IF(A2:C7<>"",A1:C1,NA()),2),
XLOOKUP(E2:E7,a,b,""))
```

[image]

(Change the ranges to your ranges)

Answer (score 0):

It is better to modified your region data like this:

[image]

so you can easily solve your problem by using **VLOOKUP** function.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is no **`Excel Constraints`** as per the tags posted, then one could try any one of the following formulas, which works dynamically and spills with one single array formula, therefore multiple iterations not required.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>G2</kbd> --> Formula needs to fill down!

```
=IF(F2="","",CONCAT(REPT(Sheet1!$A$1:$D$1,Sheet1!$A$2:$D$18=F2)))
```

---

Or,

• Formula used in cell <kbd>H2</kbd> --> Formula spills hence no need to drag!

```
=BYROW(States,LAMBDA(α,IF(α="","",CONCAT(REPT(Sheet1!$A$1:$D$1,Sheet1!$A$2:$D$18=α)))))
```

---

Or,

• Formula used in cell <kbd>I2</kbd> --> Formula needs to fill down!

```
=IF(F2="","",TOCOL(IFS(F2=Sheet1!$A$2:$D$18,Sheet1!$A$1:$D$1),3))
```

---

Or,

• Formula used in cell <kbd>J2</kbd> --> Formula spills hence no need to drag!

```
=MAP(States,LAMBDA(α,IF(α="","",TOCOL(IFS(α=Sheet1!$A$2:$D$18,Sheet1!$A$1:$D$1),3))))
```

---

Or,

• Formula used in cell <kbd>K2</kbd> --> Formula needs to fill down!

```
=IF(F2="","",CHOOSECOLS(Sheet1!$A$1:$D$1,SUM(MMULT(N(F2=Sheet1!$A$2:$D$18),{1;2;3;4}))))
```

---

Now the question is why your formula isnt working, and theoretically also dont think it should work, let me show you the screenshot below to understand clearly.

Select the top cell where the formula is entered. Goto Formulas Tab and click on `Evaluate` under the `Formula Auditing Group`, and hit <kbd>Evaluate</kbd>

[image]

---

[image]

---

Notes: Please change the cell reference or ranges or sheet tabs what ever suits with your data. Range <kbd>F2:F25</kbd> defined as `States`

---

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you create a **Table** instead of named ranges for your region lookups.

- `Name` the table `Regions`
  [image]

Then you can use this formula (assuming your `headquarters_state` column is `NAME'd` the same:

```
=LET(
    x, TOCOL(IF(Regions <> "", Regions[#Headers], NA()), 3),
    y, TOCOL(Regions, 1),
    z, XLOOKUP(headquarters_state, y, x),
    z
)
```

The results will spill down:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

### Search in Multiple Columns

**The Named Ranges**

- `Regions` - `A1:D1`
- `States` - `A2:D18`

**Formula in `G2` (Copy Down)**

- I like it simple in this case:

```
=IF(F2="","",CONCAT(IF(F2=States,Regions,"")))
```

[image]

**Formula in G2 (Spills)**

- This one should be more efficient:

```
=LET(data,F2:F12,na,"",
IF(data="","",IFNA(INDEX(Regions,
    ROUNDUP(XMATCH(data,TOCOL(States,,1))/ROWS(states),)),an)))
```

- A nice lambda function e.g. named `GetRegion` would be:

```
=LAMBDA(data,[if_not_found],
IF(data="","",IFNA(INDEX(Regions,
    ROUNDUP(XMATCH(data,TOCOL(States,,1))/ROWS(states),)),
    IF(ISOMITTED(if_not_found),"",if_not_found))))
```

when you could utilize it with a simple:

```
=GetRegion(F2:F12)
```